# identify if same value is repeated in a column using hive

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a hive table which has a column called DATALIST.It can have below values

```
XYZ_OLD
XYZ_NEW
ABC_OLD
EFG_OLD
EFG_NEW
PQR_NEW
```

I need to create an output which would identify all the names which do not have both the _NEW and _OLD in the column.In those scnarios it should output the following

```
Value  Reason
ABC    Missing NEW
PQR    Missing OLD
XYZ    Contains Both NEW and OLD
EFG    Contains both NEW and OLD
```

Any suggestion/help with the SQL/HIVEQL logic would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
select split(datalist, '_')[1],
       (case when sum(case when datalist like '%NEW' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when datalist like '%OLD' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'BOTH'
             when sum(case when datalist like '%NEW' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             then 'NEW ONLY'
             else 'OLD ONLY'
         end)

from t
group by split(datalist, '_')[1];
```

Comment: i had missed one info in the question .The names in the datalist can have multiple '_' .In that case the split would not work.Also , _OLD and _NEW maybe _OLDER and _NEWEST

Comment: @user2717470 . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: ok ..I will accept this as an answer and post a separate question .If that pleases you